# A callback function is not executed after the current effect is 100% finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm praticing jQuery/CallBack Function via https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp and as title said that **:A callback function is executed after the current effect is 100% finished.**

In my Html body i have a button and a p tag.
But when id add one more effect show with a callback function inside. It's likely not as it told before. This makes me a bit confused. Can someone explain it for me?

What i expect:Click the button => hide p tag=>**show alert "1"**=>show p tag=>**show alert "2"**
But the result:Click the button =>hide p tag => **show alert "1"** => **show alert "2"** => show p tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide("slow", function(){
      alert("1");
    });
    
    $("p").show("slow", function(){
      alert("2");
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` to prevent the `alert` blocking the UI. You may need to modify the delay to suit your needs.

```
$("p").show("slow", function(){
   setTimeout(()=>alert("2"), 0);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide("slow", function(){
      alert("1");
    });
    $("p").show("slow", function(){
      setTimeout(()=>alert("2"), 200);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
Do It
</button>
<p>
Paragraph
</p>
```

Comment: @ThịnhNguyễnVăn Then adjust the delay to a suitable value.

Comment: @ThịnhNguyễnVăn See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout